# How to show snapchat snaps on my wordpress!

Tags: homepage

I'm trying to put my snapchat snaphots on my website in realtime!
like if I have snapshot right now then it will appear in my website

Comment: You'll need to consult the snapchat documentation/APIs, assuming this is possible, this isn't a WP question. A quick google suggests that there's no official way to do this